# GoogleMaps: How to have a polygon and a marker in a single google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to combine 2 types of Drawings on a Google Maps.

> 1: Polygon - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays
>
> 2: Marker - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

I tried to merge the codes and have done various tweaks but it does not work. It either show one or the other or blank page.

Is it even possible to merge 2 drawings on a single map? Could someone give a an working example?

Comment: It is certainly possible. What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: @geocodezip I used the same map id(#map) but used different function to draw features on the map. For polygon I ran DrawPolygon() to create its polygon coordinate and then called marker to draw for list of available Marker. It does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mcve] that demonstrates what you tried that didn't work (it certainly won't work if you create two separate map objects, unless you put them in different `<div>`)

Comment: I don't want to create 2 map objects and they are on single `<div>` since I want them to load on single map.

Comment: If you aren't creating two map objects, it should "work".  Please [edit] your question to add a [mvce] that demonstrates what you tried that didn't work (second request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example of polygon and marker on the same map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polygon+marker example</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
        var triangleCoords = [
            {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
            {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
            {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
        ];

        // Construct the polygon.
        var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: triangleCoords,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);



        // marker
        var uluru = {lat: 21.5012681, lng: -84.0397756};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map,
          title: 'marker title'
        });


      }

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Don't forget to add your google maps API key instead of **YOUR_API_KEY**